# What's wrong in the following HTML page? I want to see Hello World Printed on the page

Tags: javascript, html

In the following page I want to see the div with id "divId" to display Hello World! text.
Do I have to enable something somewhere, in order to get to see that? Or I am just plain wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Hello World Page</title>
     <style type="text/css">
       <link href="some.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById('divId');// I am getting hold of that div with id "divId"
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Hello World!!!';// Adding text content to it.
     </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id ="divId">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But still I am not getting the output as dsired!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is executed before the div is added to the dom, place your script at the end of the page. In your browser console(Hit F12 to open it) you should have an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Hello World Page</title>
       <!-- external stylesheet -->
       <link href="some.css" type="text\css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!-- inline stylesheet -->
       <style type="text\css">
        #divId { ... }
       </style>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id ="divId">
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById('divId');// I am getting hold of that div with id "divId"
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Hello World!!!';// Adding text content to it.
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another option is to make use of the [window load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) handlers like

```
window.onload = function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('divId');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Hello World!!!';
}
```

Then you can put the script back in the head

Comment: Please change the backslash in type specifiers to forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your script tag in the head you would need to do the following:

*Please be aware of the lack of support of this method in older browsers.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>Hello World Page</title>
     <style type="text/css">
       <link href="some.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
             var div = document.getElementById('divId');// I am getting hold of that div with id "divId"
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Hello World!!!';// Adding text content to it.
         });

     </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id ="divId">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other than that just move it to the bottom like said in other answers.

Comment: Please change the backslash in type specifiers to forward slash.

Comment: Done, I didn't check the whole source, just copied from your question and edited.

Comment: Yeah I was at mistake.